# ADFS v4.0 and /userinfo endpoint giving 405

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, adfs

Integrating older ASP.NET server-side application into ADFS for authentication, which means I pretty much had to write everything from scratch. have everything working (/authorize, /token) up until the /userinfo call.

My code, in a nutshell -

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var req = new HttpRequestMessage {
    RequestUri = new Url("https://<server_ip>/adfs/oauth2/userinfo"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
};
req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
req.Headers.UserAgent.Clear();
req.Headers.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("OldApp", "11.3.0"));
var result = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

The result is a HTTP error 405 - Method Not Allowed. Doing searches online, I see this as a common issue when the trailing "/" is left off the url, but **I get the same result with a trailing slash**.

After poking around, there are a lot of examples that use newer libraries and such that I can't use, sadly. None mention usage of the /userinfo, and I'm thinking that the issue isn't necessarily in how I'm calling the URL, but configuration of the 'Application Group' in ADFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - I found the issue, and will document it here in case others come across the same thing..

While I am not sure why /userinfo is giving a 405 - the URL I was using is wrong, despite it being listed in the Endpoints folder. There shouldn't be any "oauth2" in the URL. The correct code (and URL) is:

```
var req = new HttpRequestMessage {
    RequestUri = new Url("https://<server_ip>/adfs/userinfo"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
};
req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
req.Headers.UserAgent.Clear();
req.Headers.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("OldApp", "11.3.0"));
var result = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

Also something to keep in mind - this has been stated elsewhere, but not as clearly as here, I hope:
The `/userinfo` will ONLY give you the NameIdentifier ("sub") claim. (As far as I can see.) No matter what scope you pass it. You will get all your information (that should normally be in the `/userinfo` call) in the "id_token" parameter from you `/token` call, encoded as JWT.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I was led to do the same thing as you, the only solution was to download the **ADAL** library ***(You will find the link below)*** and debug the code in order to re-produce the same **HTTP** stream from **ADAL**.

You can create a new project so that you can integrate **ADAL**, for debugging or else intercepting the ***HTTP*** stream

[Link ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)